# Is there a way to initilise a new list from a variable array

Tags: c#

Just new to C#.
Is there an easier way to do the following?
I've created class and I am putting its contents into a list.
I'm then building the contents of each item from some other variable array.

```
   public class GroupLine
{
    public string[] GroupA { get; set; }
    public string[] GroupB { get; set; }
    public string[] GroupC { get; set; }
    public string[] GroupD { get; set; }
}


static public class Grouptype
{
    static public List<GroupLine> Grouplayout = new List<GroupLine>();
}

GroupLine newGroupLine= new GroupLine();

newGroupLine.GroupA  = new[] { GroupA[0], GroupA[1], GroupA[2], GroupA[3], GroupA[4], GroupA[5], GroupA[6], GroupA[7], GroupA[8], GroupA[9], GroupA[10] };
newGroupLine.GroupB  = new[] { GroupB[0], GroupB[1], GroupB[2], GroupB[3], GroupB[4], GroupB[5], GroupB[6], GroupB[7], GroupB[8], GroupB[9], GroupB[10] };
newGroupLine.GroupC  = new[] { GroupC[0], GroupC[1], GroupC[2], GroupC[3], GroupC[4], GroupC[5], GroupC[6], GroupC[7], GroupC[8], GroupC[9], GroupC[10] };
newGroupLine.GroupD  = new[] { GroupD[0], GroupD[1], GroupD[2], GroupD[3], GroupD[4], GroupD[5], GroupD[6], GroupD[7], GroupD[8], GroupD[9], GroupD[10] };
       
Grouptype.Grouplayout.Add(newGroupLine);
```

The above code works but is there a way I can just use for example the GroupA[] as a range of how many it holds rather than splitting it up?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a range? It seems you want to copy either part of or an entire array, but it's a bit unclear from this incomplete code snippet which one it is

Comment: I would like to copy the entire array.

Comment: `newGroupLine.GroupA = GroupA.ToArray()` will create a copy of the in-array.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks!! That worked. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest that comes to my mind is just using [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray):

```
newGroupLine.GroupA = GroupA.ToArray();
```

This will create a shallow copy, which means the elements are references to the exact same objects as the input-array. In your case that is irrelevant, as strings are immutable anyway.

Alternativly you can use [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.copy):

```
Array.Copy(GroupA, newGroupLine.GroupA);
```